# Android: Why is Fullscreen mode still showing status bar?

Tags: android

I want my app to have fullscreen mode without appbar and statusbar. My fullscreen mode is not working properly. When I click on an EditText, the statusbar show up while focus is set on Edittext (typing).

I noticed this behaviour only for edittext's where suggestions show up. I have an Edittext for password (android:inputType="textPassword"), which shows no suggestions, and the statusbar dont show when  focus is on EditText. But with a non password EditText (android:inputType="text") where suggestions show (earlier inputs, this case emails) the statusbar shows up after focus set on Edittext.

Here is my code for hiding system UI (=having fullscreen):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

protected void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Does someone know why it behavies like this? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try this in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="full_Screen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

add add this style to your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

EDIT:

Programmatically you can do this to hide status bar

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`